# Read parameters from AWS system parameter store in cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to pull secrets(credentials) from AWS Parameters Store. Can anyone please let me know on how to use the credentials which is stored in aws parameter store

Comment: Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
     const ssm = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-ssm')
     const stringUserEmail= ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup (this, "aws ssm get-parameters --name '/vfe/webapp/dev/EVEREST_QA_VFE_INTEGRATION_USER_PASS'")
     const stringUserPassword = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup (this, '/vfe/webapp/dev/EVEREST_QA_VFE_INTEGRATION_USER_PASS')
     cy.visit(url)
cy.get(helper.logInPage.email).type(stringUserEmail)
cy.get(helper.logInPage.password).type(stringUserPassword)cy.get(helper.logInPage.signBtn).click()
     cy.wait(3000)
 })

Comment: The above code not working